# specified date range not returned properly c# - Edited

Tags: c#, .net

Got a function where it suppose to return total file size within specified  range however, it goes thru all of the files in the directory and not those between date ranges.

```
public static long fileSize(string source_path)
{
     return new DirectoryInfo(source_path).EnumerateFiles("*.SS*").Where(file => file.CreationTime < dt.AddMonths(-2)).Sum(file => file.Length);
}
```

Comment: Is di a DirectoryInfo object? If yes, why the ToString applied to a FileInfo object? Remove it.

Comment: Your `Where` lambda is not formed correctly. It is nonsensical to slap `ToString` on everything... should probably be something closer to `filename => filename.LastWriteTime >= from_date && filename.LastWriteTime <= to_date)`

Answer (score 5):

You are currently calling the `ToString()` method on your File objects and then attempting to access the [`LastWriteTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime(v=vs.110).aspx) property. This actually shouldn't even have compiled (as you would be attempting to access `LastWriteTime` from a string instead of a `FileInfo` object).

Try removing all of your `ToString()` calls and using the following :

```
// Find your files with LastWriteTimes that fall between your specific range
foreach (var file in di.EnumerateFiles("*.SS*").Where(f => f.LastWriteTime >= from_date && f.LastWriteTime <= to_date))
{
    // Iterate through your files here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why all the `ToString()`? A string does not have a `LastWriteTime` property.

Try this:

```
foreach (var filename in di.EnumerateFiles("*.SS*").Where(filename=>filename.LastWriteTime >= from_date && filename.LastWriteTime <= to_date))
```